# PynamoDB dynamic names for MapAttribute

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, pynamodb

I'm currently a bit stuck. I have to create a model of our dynamodb using pynamodb, and here's what I have (part of a bigger model, exported from a real user in DB)

```json
packs = [
  {
   "exos": {
    "4": {
     "start": 1529411739,
     "session": 1529411739,
     "finish": 1529417144
    },
    "5": {
     "start": 1529417192,
     "session": 1529417192
    }
   },
   "id": 10
  },
  {
   "exos": {
    "32": {
     "start": 1529411706,
     "session": 1529411706
    }
   },
   "id": 17
  }
 ]
```

Here's what I got so far:

```py
class ExercisesMapAttribute(MapAttribute):
    pass


class PackMapAttribute(MapAttribute):
    exos = ExercisesMapAttribute()
    id = NumberAttribute()


class TrainUser(Model):
    class Meta:
        table_name = 'TrainUser'
        region = 'eu-west-1'
    # [...] Other stuff removed for clarity
    packs = ListAttribute(of=PackMapAttribute())
```

Currently I think I got correctly up until the `"4":`, `"5":` etc... As they are exercices name.
The idea is that this structure is supposed to represent a list of packs, then inside a list of exercises with their id and more info... I need a way to map that from the current db json to classes I can then use with PynamoDB. Is it even possible?

Thanks!

I've tried `DynamicMapAttribute` but I can't figure out if it will work with my configuration.
I also don't know how a custom attribute could be done to overcome this.